# Using javascript regex containing '@' in razor

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am performing email address validation with javascript in a razor view page. 
The regex I am going to use is similar to the one proposed at [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

However, because the regex contains an '@' character, I am getting parser error when try to run the web app.

my regex looks like

```
/^...otherpart @* ... other part$/
```

I tried to add an '@' character to make the  in the origin regex ... @@* ..., this eliminated the compilation error but seems to make the regex stops working. (we have used it in another web app that does not use razor engine, so I know it works).

Is there any other way to escape the '@' character?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your script block with `<text><script>...</script></text>`?

Comment: @Jasen I have not tried the <text></text> trick. Will try tomorrow and let you know the result.

Comment: If you use this script is several places it's probably a good idea to put it in it's own .js file. Individual validation rules, such as max/min, could be put in data- attributes for elements and read via jQuery.

Comment: @Jasen,@jfankcarr.
I have taken your advise and used a separate file and everything is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add another `@` in front of it to escape `@@`, try leaving out the quantifer `*`. If this doesn't seem to work then add `<text></text>` around the function, it tells Razor to not parse the contents. Alternatively you can put Javascript in a separate file to accomplish your needs.

If for some reason you have multiple `@@` in your string, place code blocks ahead `@:@@`

Comment: I've tried a few things... `<text>` and beginning the line with `@:` but only `@@` appears to do the trick. The other option is to use a separate file.

Comment: I would be inclined to put all of that into a separate file instead of writing a funky regex pattern to satisfy the Razor parser. Sometimes it's hard enough understanding a regex pattern without having to think about escaped characters.

Answer (score 15):

Put the following inside the regEx instead of @:

```
@('@')
```

The above will be rendered to a single @.

Your example will become:

```
/^...otherpart @('@')* ... other part$/
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Doubling up the @@ changes your REGEX and that's not what you want. still, I wish there were a better way to scape the @ sign in razor, something like \@

Answer (score 0):

Simply just use double `@@`.
It works for me and I think that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use @('@') instead of @@ (not working for me).
**Example**

```
<input class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z@('@')]{5,20}$"/>
```