# ng-pattern not accepting '@' special character in validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

NET MVC, HTML 5 and Angularjs, i am having trouble on using ng-pattern in the password field validation.
this is my pattern

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!#$%^&*])[a-z0-9!#$%^&*]{8,16}$/"
```

I need to validate the passwoerd field must contains minimum 8 characters and contains alphanumeric and atleast 1 special character. when i use @ as a special character in the password field the error says use atleast one special character. regex pattern not considering @ as a special character.

Also i have included @ symbol in this group **!@#$%^&*** in the above pattern though its giving the error in my MVC page.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the @ with `@@`?

Comment: In Razor MVC, `@` must be doubled. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440990/using-javascript-regex-containing-in-razor - try `@('@')`

Comment: Sometimes using `@@` doesn't work, but you can "cheat" like this: `@("@")`

Comment: wow...!!! its worked thanks man @DavidG and all