# Issue with regex when I mix razor and JS and use <text> </text>

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, razor

This question is an epilogue of the great question [Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code) where I learn about this syntax:

```
@if (foo)
{
    // C# code
    <text>
    // JS Code
    </text>
}
```

It worked well, until today, when I used a JS regex inside the `<text></text>` :

```
$('#bar').html(boo.replace(/<br([\/ ]*)>/g, "\r\n"));
```

Which throw a yellow page telling me that there was an issue with `br(` which can't be analyzed.

Is there an inline way to deal with it?

Comment: Did you try escaping it? `/\<br([\/ ]*)>/`

Comment: @MikeC same result :/

Comment: You might try the `@()` syntax suggested in the answer to [Using javascript regex containing '@' in razor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34580370/215552). Additionally, there's a great answer on [Using Razor within JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4599403/215552) that might help. It might be nice to update your title too to reflect that you've got the angle brackets. Otherwise, with the title being just like a ton of other questions, it tends to look like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(replaced my previous answer)

I tested this code in an MVC View, and it works:

```
<div id="bar" style="border: 1px solid black">
    Dummy content (should be replaced)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var boo = "<span>hello<br />world</span>";
    var symbolLT = "<";
    @if (1 == 1)
    {
        // C# code
        <text>
        var regex = new RegExp(symbolLT + "br([\/ ]*)>", "g");
        $('#bar').html(boo.replace(regex, "\r\n"));
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

The trick is to isolate the `"<"` character from the `<text></text>` block, *and* to use `new RegExp()`. Perhaps a bit less readable than a normal inline expression, but it surely works.

Or you can simply create the regex earlier on the page, so outside of the `<text></text>` block, and then use it inside.